# Java game sound effects isn't working correctly

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip

I'm trying to do my school project (a simple Java game) and I cant's get the sound effects work. I'm doing it using Clip and now my playSound-method looks like this:

```
public void playSound(File filename) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(filename);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(sound);

        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have different sound effects as attributes (Files) and I call that method when I want to play some sound.

Everything works fine: the sound plays for example when the player eats something but sometimes the sounds go grazy. The eating sound is being played while the player isn't eating anything.

Do you know what's wrong? Is it problematic to play several sound effects like this? Thanks! :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What formats are your sound files?  It could make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The following advice may or may not help with your situation.

You are loading Clips from disk every time you play a sound. Clips were designed to be loaded once, and called on an as-needed basis. To replay a clip, you reset it back to the 0th millisecond or frame and then call play as you do here. This way, it starts very quickly. The way you have programmed it, the clip will not even start playing until it has fully loaded from disk into memory, and the setFramePosition(0) is superfluous since a newly created Clip will always play from the start (unless you've explicitly set it to some other frame position).

So, I recommend at the start of the game, loading the clips once into objects that will persist, and reference them on an as-needed basis, at which time you only need to call the setFramePosition(0) and the play() methods.

If the sounds are playing at odd times, I'd take a harder look at the logic that calls the sounds. While your method is not optimal, it does work, and would only result in oddly late play times if the loading of the sound file were delayed for some reason or another. But if your sounds are more than a few seconds long, those loading delays could be the source of the problem.

One other thought, a SourceDataLine will start playing more quickly than creating, loading and playing a new Clip. It takes a bit more cpu to play an SDL than a Clip, but it is still a reasonable way to go if the sound files are on the long side.